# Angular 2 : Trouble with asynchronous data

Tags: angular, observable, ag-grid

I made a service that provide data. When I return directly the data, it works :

```
When I return directly the data, it works. Like that :

 return [
            {
                "prop1": "value1",
                "prop2": "value2"  
            },
            {
                "prop1": "value3",
                "prop2": "value6"
            }
        ];
```

But when I try to get them from a JSON file, it doesn't :

```
// Get Data from JSON
private _getDataFromJson(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url)
               .toPromise()
               .then(res => res.json())
               .then(data => { return data; })
}
// I also tested that
/*return this.http.get(this._generateUrl(type, 'column-def'))
             .map(res => res.json());*/
```

I'm using those json files datas for ag grid (default colDef, colDef, floatingTopRows and datasource). I'm not sure if it's related or not.

My code look like that :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.defaultColDef = this.FakeData.getColumnDefDefault();
    this.colDef = this.FakeData.getColumnDef(this.dataType);
    this.floatingTopRowData =  this.FakeData.getFloatingTopRows(this.dataType);
    this.allOfTheData = this.FakeData.getData(this.dataType);

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions> {
            onGridReady: () => {
                this._populateData();
            }
    };
}
```

Other related methods :

```
_populateData(): void {
    this.allOfTheData.then(rowData => {
        this._setRowData(rowData);
        this.pageSizes = this._generatePageSizes(rowData.length);
    });
}

_setRowData(rowData): void {
    this.allOfTheData = rowData;
    this._createNewDatasource();
}

_createNewDatasource(): void {
    if(!this.allOfTheData) return;

    let dataSource = {
        getRows: (params: any) => {
            this.sortedAndFilteredData = this._sortAndFilter(params.sortModel, params.filterModel);
            let rowsThisPage = this.sortedAndFilteredData.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
            params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, this.sortedAndFilteredData.length);
        }
    };

    this.gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
}
```

**EDIT**

My template :

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid [id]="id" style="width: 100%;" [style.height.px]="gridHeight" class="ag-bootstrap" (modelUpdated)="setHeight()"
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
[columnDefs]="colDef"
[floatingTopRowData]="floatingTopRowData"
enableColResize
enableServerSideSorting
enableServerSideFilter
suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns
suppressMultiSort
rowModelType="pagination"
[headerHeight]="headerHeight"
[rowHeight]="rowHeight" 
rowSelection="multiple"
(dragStopped)="_onColumnMoved()"
(selectionChanged)="_onSelectionChanged()">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
private _getDataFromJson(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url)
           .toPromise()
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(data => { return data; })
}
```

This method is returning a promise, therefore, the calling method will need to use the promise to get the data.

So calling `_getDataFromJson(url)` would look something like this:

```
this._getDataFromJson(someUrl).then(data => this.foo = data);
```

Or since you're using Typescript, you can use async/await:

```
this.foo = await this._getDataFromJson(someUrl);  // don't forget the async keyword on the enclosing method
```

Comment: `foo` or `food`? Somebody must be hungry ;-)

Comment: Thank you. When I try the first solution, I get an error : error_handler.js:50 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./myComponent class MyComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
Error: Error in ./MyComponent class MyComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Can you provide more implementation details?  The code snippet you provided doesn't appear to show how you are actually using this method.  Also, maybe any html/template code you can provide as well.

Comment: All of the FakeData methods are returning  this._getDataFromJson(this._generateUrl(someParams). I have added my template.

Comment: Well if you used the first solution, then your fakeData methods are probably also returning promises.  I'm sorry, it's hard to tell what's going on.  Depending on how you have this code written, you may also need to handle the fakeData methods as promises too.  Also, not sure if you've seen this, but perhaps this ext can help you inspect what's bound to your component elements: https://github.com/rangle/augury

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand. I will take a look at that link.